Dynamic AWS::accountId and AWS::region in a device provisioning template policy document
I am trying to implement IoT device provisioning in AWS by trusted user via provisioning template.
My provisioning template is as follows:
{ 
    "Parameters": {
        "ThingName" : {
            "Type" : "String"
        },
        "Company": {
            "Type" : "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources" : {
        "thing" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Thing",
            "Properties" : {
                "ThingName" : {"Ref" : "ThingName"},
                "AttributePayload" : {
                    "Company" :  {"Ref" : "Company"}
                }, 
                "ThingTypeName" :  "My-Thing-Type"
            },
            "OverrideSettings" : {
                "AttributePayload" : "REPLACE",
                "ThingTypeName" : "REPLACE"
            }
        },  
        "certificate" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
                "CertificateId": {"Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"},
                "Status" : "ACTIVE"
            }
        },
        "policy" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Policy",
            "Properties" : {
                "PolicyDocument" : {
                    "Fn::Sub": [
                        "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\": [{\"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": \"iot:Connect\", \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:client/${ThingName}\"}, {\"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": \"iot:Subscribe\", \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topicfilter/companies/${Company}/devices/${ThingName}/events\" }, { \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": \"iot:Receive\", \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topic/companies/${Company}/devices/${ThingName}/events\"} , { \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": \"iot:Publish\", \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topic/companies/${Company}/devices/${ThingName}/events\" }]}",
                        {
                            "ThingName":{
                                "Ref":"ThingName"
                            },
                            "Company":{
                                "Ref":"Company"
                            }
                        } 
                    ] 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I would expect the AWS::Region and AWS::AccountId reserved variables to be automatically replaced upon provisioning, but they remain unchanged in the created policy document.
I then tried to expressly pass the following further arguments to the Fn::Sub:
"AWS::Region":{
   "Ref":"AWS::Region"
},
"AWS::AccountId":{
   "Ref":"AWS::AccountId"
}

But an error sent to the $aws/provisioning-templates/{MY-PROVISIONING-TEMPLATE-NAME}/provision/json topic indicates that the variables cannot be resolved: {"statusCode":400,"errorCode":"InvalidParameters","errorMessage":"Cannot resolve reference value: AWS::Region"}.
